# Как установить примеры в qt

Tags: qt

Собрал Qt через MSYS2, теперь нужны примеры какая есть команда в shell для установки примеров? (стоит mingw64).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если уж вы собрали `Qt` из исходников, то соберите и примеры:

- Перейдите в директорию с исходным кодом `Qt`, далее в
  `qtbase/examples`;
- Чтобы собрать все примеры сразу (потребуется много
  времени и места на диске):

  `$ qmake`

  `$ make`

(или для Windows: `qmake.exe` и `mingw64-make.exe` соответственно).

Можете собирать примеры по отдельности, только интересующие:

- Перейдите в директорию нужного проекта (например,
  `qtbase/examples/gui/analogclock`);
- Выполняете описанные выше действия `qmake` и `make`.

Немного пояснения для новичка:

`qmake` - программа создаёт на основе файла описания проекта `.pro` сценарий сборки (`Makefile`), характерный для вашей конфигурации системы.

`make` - собственно выполняет сценарий сборки, т.е. собирает исполняемый модуль (приложение, библиотеку) из исходного кода (запускает компилятор и линковщик).

Comment: Благодарю за совет, но вы меня не совсем верно поняли. Для сборки Qt я использовал msys2 installer, где через консоль полностью автоматизировано можно собрать Qt с пол пинка как динамику так и статику. Просто у меня рейтинга не хватает поставить тег msys2. У меня все прекрасно работает, но сейчас начал изучать OpenGL и нужны примеры - это разумеется не критично, но все равно неприятно.